# Unable to debug code of methods outside of xunit tests

Tags: c#, debugging, xunit, breakpoints

I have some xunit tests. One of them takes list of args from a function that is, obiously, not a test itself. Problem is, **breakpoints are never hit** in that function, or anywhere but inside xunit tests.

And it worked for me at the beggining. I must have done something to break it, but I have to idea where to look for a root cause of my debugger to not working anymore outside of tests

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> GenerateGetPositiveTestCases()
{
    (...) <- BREAKPOINT HERE NEVER WORKS
    return TestFunctions.GenerateTestCases(); <- BREAKPOINT HERE NEVER WORKS 
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GenerateGetPositiveTestCases))]
public void TestGetResponse200(string endpoint)
{
    (...) <- BREAKPOINT HERE ALWAYS WORKS
}
```

Just to add, code works fine and function GenerateGetPositiveTestCases is called.
What may be causing it?